# airflow 2.5.0 how to get upstream_task_ids in airflow.models.BaseOperator or filter task_ids to get only downstream task ids

Tags: airflow

I am trying to follow documentation when upgrading from 2.2.1 to 2.5.0 but no luck to find out this old good **upstream_task_ids** https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator.upstream_task_ids:

in 2.5.0 docs

> task_ids (str | list[str] | None) – Only XComs from tasks with
> matching ids will be pulled. Can pass None to remove the filter.

or how can one apply filters to get only downstream task ids out of task_ids ??

Comment: I think it's still there, it's just not documented

Comment: @mck It smels not: I got AttributeError: class 'my.smth.XYZperator' extending BaseOperator does not have the attribute 'upstream_task_ids'

Comment: It is in BaseOperator, see [the source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fa2bec042995004f45b914dd1d66b466ccced410/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L887). Can you provide a [mcve] which shows that you cannot access the attribute in an extended custom operator?